# RegExp: найти квадратную скобку "[" если перед ней не стоит слово "foo"?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

RegExp: найти квадратную скобку "[" если перед ней не стоит слово "foo"?

```
bar[ <--- это найти
foo[ <--- а это не надо
```

Спасибо!

Comment: в js regex нет lookbehind, а без этого одним выражением нельзя правильно сделать match

Answer (score 1):

`(?<!\bfoo)\[`
Можно решить данный вопрос используя негативный просмотр назад, так же указать в нем `\b` граница слова (работает только с латинскими буквами)

**input:**

```
foo[
afoo[
bar[
alala bar[asa
alala foo[asa
```

**match:**

```
foo[
afoo[
----^
bar[
---^
alala bar[asa
---------^---
alala foo[asa
```

Пример:
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xBx13T/3)

Comment: А, тема опять 3 летней давности) Ну и обоснованный минус конечно же =)

Comment: Да нужно убирать эту возможность поднятия старых тем, очень старые темы в `IT` теряют свою релевантность, тем более эту тему никто уже не отметит галочкой и она будет подниматься и подниматься в будущем даже если ответ решает полностью заданный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение будет вроде этого

```
^(?!foo).*\[
```

[explain](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fBza6sdX_SpMrSmN)

На `JS` будет так

```
var regexp = new RegExp("^(?!foo).*\\[");
var string = 'bar[';

console.log(string.search(regexp));
```

Comment: `var string = 'afoo[';`

Comment: @zb' - Вроде в описание сказано, **найти квадратную скобку "[" если перед ней не стоит слово "foo"?**. Если у вас есть рабочие решение скиньте

Comment: Одним регекспом на js никак, нужен  backreference

Comment: На самом деле всегда в таких случаях важно знать исходные данные и зачем искать,

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov а почему не так "(?<!foo)\[" вы решил написать? Мне кажется это более правильно

Comment: @zb' согласен, нужно знать исходные данные

Comment: @ИльяБабушкин я ваш шаблон в браузере кидаю, но он что-то ругается. А так в принципе, разница думаю не большая как пишешь, главное что бы работала